# Identifying Home Wifi Bottleneck

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, switch

I'm trying to understand if I've got a bottleneck in my home network setup or if my expectations are off. Here's my situation:

- Xfinity Comcast is my internet provider and I'm paying for a 300 Mbps plan
- I consistently get 300+ Mbps over wifi with both phone and Mac when standing near the router

In my home office I was getting poor speeds (10-40 Mbps) over wifi. In an attempt to improve that, I installed a [TP-Link AC1750](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K4DS67C) in the office (my house was wired in 2003 with Cat 5 ethernet cabling throughout).

That definitely helped and now I'm getting 50-90 Mbps over wifi in that (smallish) room.

My guess is that I should be able to come closer to the full 300 Mbs considering the office router is hard-wired to the Xfinity router.

That got me thinking that maybe the old school [Linksys EZXS16W EtherFast 10/100 16-Port Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00005854F) that is connecting all the rooms in the house was a bottleneck? If I'm understanding the specs correctly, it maxes out at 100 Mbps?

Do I need to upgrade my switch to something like this [TP-Link 16-Port Gigabit Switch](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/unmanaged-switch/tl-sg1016d/) that looks like it can handle 1000 Mbps if I want to get better speeds?

Thanks much for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am only slightly jealous that you're getting 300Mbps to your house. Having said that, you're correct that the issue is the 100Mbps switch being the bottleneck. 90Mbps is about the actual throughput such a switch could provide and you're seeing that on on the office router because it's on the other side of the switch from your primary router. A gigabit switch will solve this problem for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will now purchase more gear with confidence :)